# WordPress: deleted page still showing up and the slug is broken

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a WordPress page with a slug "blog" and I'm trying to delete it and create a new one with the same name, but even when I delete it, it still shows, i cleared the caches and i change the theme because I have a custom theme that i made to make sure it not a theme problem, but it still showing that page

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is a topic for a wordpress forum. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try to disabled all plugins

Comment: @DanyialShahidAli I did, and still the same, I think the database corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these quick steps, I think that will 90% works.

1. First backup your website, There are a lot of plugins that can do that perfectly with one click.
2. Then reset your database, also there're a lot of plugins that can do that.
3. check if the page still exists.
4. If the problem is fixed then reinstall your theme, and use the backup file you made and you're all set!

Hope that helps!